# L'emploi en substantif de « fatigant » est-il un régionalisme ?

Tags: québec, régionalismes, lexique

Seul *Wiktionnaire* recense le substantif [fatigant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fatigant#Nom_commun) pour la « personne importune, ennuyeuse » et il n'est pas identifié comme étant régional. Or un exemple est québécois et l'autre est le suivant :

> Toi, mon fatigant, va voir ailleurs si j’y suis !

A-t-on simplement oublié la mention *régionalisme* (Québec/Canada) — et si c'est le cas l'associe-t-on au lexique québécois quand on le trouve — dit-on ça régionalement ailleurs ou est-ce usuel partout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien que je comprendrais le sens si on me disait de quelqu'un que *c'est un fatigant* ou *une fatigante*, je pencherais pour un régionalisme, ne me souvenant pas l'avoir entendu utilisé comme substantif en France. *Mon fatigant* me poserait plus de problèmes.

Ce que j'entends de proche :

> *Celui-là, il me fatigue !*

Comment: @Ti-cul ti-caille: bonjour de Belgique ! "Mon fatigant" n'est pas utilisé en Belgique. Par contre, ce "mon" dans une interpellation est aussi utilisé en Belgique (et en France à mon avis) avec certaines insultes, et tendent à les atténuer: "mon con", "mon salaud", etc.

Comment: @Greg Oui, ici aussi: *Ben mon salaud !* *mon couillon*, *mon cochon...* :-)

Comment: Aussi "mais qu'est ce que tu m'as foutu?" :-)

Answer (score 3):

La nominalisation d'un adjectif qui correspond à une caractéristique envisagée comme inhérente à une personne est un processus normal en français (*un dépressif, un endormi, un aveugle, un roux* etc. etc.).

Mon Robert ne marque pas non plus cet usage de *fatigant* comme étant régional. Toutefois, je suis d'accord que ***la fréquence* de ce mot (ou, pour prendre un autre exemple, de *insignifiant*) comme terme appliqué à une personne est considérablement plus élevée au Québec qu'en France**. Cela s'explique probablement parce que les Français préfèrent dire qu'une personne est *rasante* ou *barbante*, mots qui ne sont pas du tout en usage au Québec.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que *rasant* ou *barbant* soient plus courants en France aujourd'hui. Ces mots me semblent un peu passés de mode à l'oral et de toute façon, ne sont pas vraiment utilisés comme substantifs. D'autre part, leur sens me parait est plus restreint, essentiellement limité à *boring* alors que fatigant ajoute le sens d'énervant, pénible (*annoying*)